# How to know when UITextView became first responder

Tags: ios, ios4, uitextview

How to handle when uitextview became first responder. I have text in text view and I want when the view became active want to clear the text. How can I do that? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 61):

You can definitely use a `UITextViewDelegate` method of:

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
```

Just return YES and intercept inside that method. You can also do it for `UITextFields` with `UITextFieldDelegate` and:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

Comment: Doesn't work if the TextView's `isEditable` property has been set to `false`

Comment: @SepehrBehroozi Why would Textview become firstresponder if it can't be edited in the first place?

Answer (score 6):

`textViewShouldBeginEditing` actually triggers before the text view becomes the first responder.

`textViewDidBeginEditing` will trigger once the text view becomes the first responder and would be the best place to execute code that needs to know what the active textview is.

If you are not really worried about which field is active and just want to clear the text once the field is tapped on you could use either function.

EDIT: The same methods are available for text fields.

Answer (score 4):

As above, you can override becomeFirstResponder but note that you must call the superclass implementation. If you don't, things like popping the keyboard on a text field won't work. i.e.

```
override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
  if super.becomeFirstResponder() {
    // set up the control state
    return true
  }

  return false
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The Swift 4 solution

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {           
        return true
 }
```

Comment: Did you mean `textViewDidBeginEditing`?

Comment: @raurora there is a method for TextFieldDelegate called textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_:) as well https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619601-textfieldshouldbeginediting

Answer (score 3):

Previous answers do the job great for UITextBox, but if you have a custom class derived from NSResponder and need to know when it becomes first responder:

```
-(BOOL) becomeFirstResponder
{
    // Your stuff here
    return YES;
}
```